# parse format data

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a Data item in my list SharePoint. It's look like this :  2014-10-16T11:00:00:00Z
How can I eliminate the T and Z without parse coding , if there is an out-of-box or an xslt code that I add It with SharePoint designer2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for ddwrt:FormatDate function:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshuag/archive/2009/03/25/custom-date-formats-in-sharepoint-xsl.aspx

http://autosponge.wordpress.com/2008/05/09/ddwrt-formatdate-and-formatdatetime/

Comment: I ad this: <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(@DateOrg,1033,2)"/>